# Trying to get FBX import add on

Tags: add-on

I think the link is missing to this addon

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX

Anyone know how I can get this? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to get it...it should be in your blender by default. What version of Blender are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is built into Blender.  Go to *File -> User Preferences... -> Add-ons* and type "FBX" into the search box at the top.  Put a checkmark on the FBX plugin to activate it.